# Supporting toolbar visibility in macOS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout, macos-mojave

I was testing how an existing application works on Mojave and I found strange problem with the layout. Toggle window toolbar visibility off then back on makes toolbar to appear on top of the content instead of pushing it down.

Snippet:

```
CustomPopUp *popup = [CustomPopUp popup];
__weak CustomRevealViewController *rev = self.revealViewController;
__weak NSWindow *window = self.view.window;
// Called when user taps in the popup view
[popup setCloseAction:^(BOOL success){
    [rev removeOverlayController];
    // !!! After this layout breaks
    [window.toolbar setVisible:YES];
}];
[window.toolbar setVisible:NO];
[self.revealViewController showOverlayController:popup];
```

Any idea what could cause the problem and how to fix it?

**Edit 1:**

I've created a simple project [here](https://github.com/ASPetrov/iTestToolbar).

Steps to reproduce:

> 1. Run the project with Xcode 10 beta (Requires Mac OSX Mojave)
> 2. Press "Hide toolbar" button. This will hide the toolbar and will
>          update the button title.
> 3. Press "Show toolbar"

Resut:

> Toolbar looks broken. It is over the controller.

Expected result:

> It should work like on any other OS version. Controller's top constraint should be moved down.

**Edit 2:**

Maybe I found a clue in the [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.14 beta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/appkit_release_notes_for_macos_10.14_beta?language=objc) under **Layer-Backed Views** section.

> Views that implicitly depend on being redrawn when an ancestor,
>   descendant, or intersecting sibling is redrawn may not be redrawn. As
>   before, if a view needs to be redrawn, set its needsDisplay property
>   to YES. Views that return YES from wantsUpdateLayer will typically be
>   given an exclusive layer, even if the view's wantsLayer property is
>   set to NO. Apps targeting macOS 10.14 should prefer the
>   wantsUpdateLayer property over the wantsLayer property.

I'm still not sure how to fix it.

**Edit 3:**
With the official release of Mojave this is no longer an issue. Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10 beta for this?

Comment: Yes, Xcode 10 beta.

Comment: So maybe there is an API change that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I have a spash window without toolbar and then I fade it out and show another window with a toolbar.

The window with toolbar has broken layout in official release of Mojave (view appears beneath the toolbar). To fix it, I hide and then show again window's toolbar:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear];
    if (_firstTime) {
        _firstTime = NO;
        NSWindow *window = self.view.window;

        window.toolbar.visible = NO;
        window.toolbar.visible = YES;
    }
 }
```